# Condittional formatting wont work on the entire range selected

Tags: excel

I am trying to format(gray fill and strikethough) a range of cells ( A101 to  D115)based on the input of another cell- D75 (possible values yes/no dropdown)

When I format the individual cells, it works but when the range is selected, only the top left cell is formatted.

The conditional formatting details pane shows the range but the display does not show the format.

Comment: What is your condition?

Comment: I have a cell with dropdown values yes or no. When the user chooses no, the next few rows should be grayed out. I am using =D65="No" as the condition.

Comment: Try using `$D$65`